# change wordpress image upload to another directory in public_html

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I want to set my wordpress files to upload to /home/public_html/images instead of /wp_content/uploads, I have gotten to the point that it gives me the correct url for /home/public_html/images but I have to move the new files from /wp_content/uploads to /home/public_html/images for it to work

I have tried changing the upload path in wp-options.php but that just makes a subdirectory in my sites folder called public_html and puts the image there instead of actually putting it in /home/public_html/images

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the wp_config.php file and adding this line of code:

```
define('UPLOADS', 'images');
```

This should put the images in a folder under /public_html instead of the typical /wp_content folder.

https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/wp-config-php/#moving-uploads-folder

Comment: that changes it to a directory called images within the wordpress folder